# How to listen to an ajax change effecting DOM in python?

Tags: python, ajax

There is a site that uses a comit/meteor server that adds rows to a table they
have in their front page.

I want to listen to the changes and capture any new tr's that are popping out.
How can i do that in python? i'm fairly new with the language coming from php.

**EDIT:** here is the [website](http://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/). Notice every few seconds a few new ip's are populated to the table. I want to listen to those changes and extract the ip and port of all new entries.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I find it very hard to figure out what you are asking here. It would help if you included some code to show what you have tried, it'll make it much easier for us to help you. Perhaps you could also take a look at http://whathaveyoutried.com for a great article on how to ask good questions?

Comment: @MartijnPieters i'm sorry for being vague. i've added an example of my problem

Comment: @Tom: How is it related to python?

Comment: @Thrustmaster web development is extremely related to python. I can do this in Java or php but i would like to learn how to approach this in python

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not really the place to ask questions as vague as this; see the [faq#dontask].

Comment: @Tom: Please improve your question. At ~700 rep, you should really know  [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Besides, I meant how exactly is python put to use in here.

Comment: @Thrustmaster there isn't anything to change. it's a simple question: "How to listen to DOM changes in python" is clear enough. anyone that has any clue with javascript would agree. You both down voted because it's not your field. So next time please don't troll threads

Comment: @Tom Oh, please. Python by itself can **not** do it. May be if that server serves you the table as a part of the HTML page, you are in luck(Google for mechanize). With what you expect, I can tell you do not understand how that page works, the client-server model (with a python client), or the way javascript operates. Please atleast google, before you speak out something in a condescending tone. (PS: If it wasn't my field, I wouldn't care to open the question)

Comment: And to point you towards the answer, there's an AJAX request hitting: `http://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/xhr/update/50`. You need to parse out the HTML within the JSON response.

Comment: @Thrustmaster just solved it. it wasn't even hard. pretty easy i might say. i really don't know why you attacked me with your attitude but i guess people are like that. either way thanks

Comment: @Tom: No one attacked you; if you felt I did, I am sorry. Next time dont call anyone trolls or use a condescending tone (and may be my attitude was because of that) -- We are taking out time to help you. And glad that you fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [selenium python binding](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/index.html#use-the-source-luke) which imitated the browser with the javascript functionality perfectly. I've found out that [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) was also a good solution with the draw back of having to refresh the page every few seconds (because it doesn't execute the javascript, only scrapes it)